# Change ACL permissions out

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to change the permissions output file context from:

Account         Folder Path IdentityReference   AccessControlType   IsInherited InheritanceFlags    PropagationFlags
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM AllowFALSEContainerInherit ObjectInheritNone    \uklonfap11\data\apps\ACCESS2  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow   FALSE   ContainerInherit     ObjectInherit  None
BUILTIN\Administrators  AllowFALSEContainerInherit ObjectInheritNone    \uklonfap11\data\apps\ACCESS2  BUILTIN\Administrators  Allow   FALSE   ContainerInherit     ObjectInherit  None

To something like:

Account Ace String  Object Path
SYSTEM  Allow  Full Control, this folder, subfolders and files (Inherited)  \UKSHEFAP08\e$\Data\Global\PHE test cases\back up of phe\Test cases\Benefit statements
Everyone    Allow  Modify, this folder, subfolders and files (Inherited)    \UKSHEFAP08\e$\Data\Global\PHE test cases\back up of phe\Test cases\Benefit statements

Does this make sense or it requires a complete change to the code: a snippet of the code is:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\AoN Project\Execute\Output.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

$isInherited = @{
 $true  = 'Inherited'
 $false = 'Not Inherited'
}

$inheritance = @{
 0 = 'files only'
 1 = 'this folder and subfolders'
 2 = 'this folder and files'
  3 = 'subfolders and files'
}

$fldr = $Folder.FullName

$Folders | % {
$fldr = $_.FullName
Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access |
 select @{n='Account';e={$_.IdentityReference}},
     @{n='ACE String';e={"{0} {1}, {2} ({3})" -f $_.AccessControlType,
       $_.FileSystemRights, $inheritance[$_.InheritanceFlags],
       $isInherited[$_.IsInherited]}},
     @{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}}}
```

Comment: Looks like you want a CSV file. If so, don't reinvent the wheel. Use `Select-Object` or format as [custom table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx). Then export with `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use calculated properties for this:

```
$fldr = $Folder.FullName
Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access |
  select @{n='Account';e={$_.IdentityReference}},
         @{n='ACE String';e={"{0} {1}, {2} ({3})" -f $_.AccessControlType,
           $_.FileSystemRights, $_.InheritanceFlags, $_.IsInherited}},
         @{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}}
```

Custom text can be provided via hashtables, e.g.:

```
$isInherited = @{
  $true  = 'Inherited'
  $false = 'Not Inherited'
}

$inheritance = @{
  0 = 'files only'
  1 = 'this folder and subfolders'
  2 = 'this folder and files'
  3 = 'subfolders and files'
}

$fldr = $Folder.FullName
Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access |
  select @{n='Account';e={$_.IdentityReference}},
         @{n='ACE String';e={"{0} {1}, {2} ({3})" -f $_.AccessControlType,
           $_.FileSystemRights, $inheritance[$_.InheritanceFlags.value__],
           $isInherited[$_.IsInherited]}},
         @{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}}
```

However, permissions displayed in the GUI sometimes consist of more than a single ACE, so there is no simple way to achieve exactly what you want. You'd have to evaluate all ACEs of any given ACL and merge the ones matching particular criteria into a single display record.

---

As a side note: you shouldn't hand-craft CSVs. Let PowerShell do the work for you:

```
$Folders | % {
  $fldr = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access | ...
} | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoType
```